# DocProperty "Pages" changed by printing

Tags: printing, microsoft-word-2007, field-codes

I'm using a feature in Word that has worked for me for more than a decade:  in the Footer, I select "Insert", "Quick Parts", "Field..." then Field names: "Page".  I type "`of`", then insert the "DocProperty Pages" field.  Now, in the footer of page 3, for example, I see `3 of 5` (if the document has five pages). If the document grows, I "Select All" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>), then "Update" (<kbd>F9</kbd>).

In my current document, all works great until I print.  The "Pages" field gets reset to 1 before it prints.  After this, if I select it and update, it reverts to the correct value, but printing always resets it to 1.  Anyone have an idea what could be going on?

Comment: @pnuts: This is a document I created from scratch.  I'm working in a corporate environment, and there are a couple of laser printers I'm linked to more or less "permanently".  As a test, I tried "printing" to a PDF document: same results.

Comment: @pnuts: As for selecting "3 of 5" instead of Ctrl+A, that works, too.  I can just select the "Pages" field by itself and update.  That has all worked correctly.  It's the resetting to "1" when I print that I don't understand.  It must be something about this environment.

Comment: To @pnuts: re: "previously compliant" -- this is a new from-scratch document, so "previously compliant" is meaningless.  There was no "previous".

Comment: To @pnuts: re: (b): the problem has nothing to do with various methods of selecting the field and updating.  Ctrl+A, individually selected, doesn't matter.  The correct value gets put in the field when I "Update Field" or F9.  The problem is the resetting of the field when I print -- to any device.

Comment: @CHOeld, Does this document differ in any way to the others? For example do you have a header/footer structure that is different to your other documents?

Answer (score -2):

Well, I seem to have a solution, even though some of this still doesn't make sense:

Someone here suggested I might be using the wrong field code for the number of pages in the document, so I went looking again through the field codes and Voila! There's one in the "Document Information" category called { NumPages }.  As a test, I stuck it in the footer beside { Pages }, printed, and Lo and Behold, it doesn't get reset.  Success.  I'm guessing that this is the field code I've always used before, but didn't completely remember.

But the really weird thing is, with { NumPages } in there, { Pages } doesn't get reset.  Go figure.